# Работа post запроса с API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, post, requests

У меня есть скрипт, который по API получает данные от одного сервиса. Выдержка из документации API:

> Перечень методов:
>   3. getissues – получение списка обращений (в данном методе используется параметр page, описанный в начале документа) Метод
>   получает список обращений, на одной странице отдается 15 обращений.
>
> Входные параметры
>   - PARTNER – JSON объект со списком идентификаторов источников, не обязательный, в случае не указания будет выбран список открытых
>   источников по-умолчанию
>   - STATUS – идентификатор статуса
>   - CATEGORY – JSON объект со списком категорий

Есть пример рабочего кода на php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$wsdl = 'https://example.ru/api.php?action=getissues&page=1';
$soap = curl_init($wsdl);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'PARTNER={"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}');
$messageID = curl_exec($soap);
print_r(json_decode($messageID));
curl_close($soap); \r\n
```

Мой запрос к api на python:

```
import json
import requests 

data = {"PARTNER": [{"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}]}
list_for_all = []
for n in range(5):
    api_url = f"https://example.ru/api.php?action=getissues&page={n}"
    res1 = requests.post(api_url, json=data)
    res = json.loads(res1.text)
    res2 = res['RESULTS']
    list_for_all.append(res2)

print(list_for_all)
```

API  в моем запросе отдает мне общедоступные источники (см. выдержку из документации), так как будто post запроса с параметром PARTNER  и не было.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и что мне нужно исправить в коде, чтобы он отдал данные только с источниками указанными в post запросе?

UPD: Создатель API подсказывает, что PARTNER должен быть не ключом в json объекте, а параметром post запроса. Но как это сделать через модуль requests , если там в параметрах post запроса может быть только data и json я не понимаю

> Привет Как-то у тебя не так выглядят данные У меня нет сейчас доступа
>   к описанию, но по примеру https://example.ru/test_api_response.php там
>   должен быть не json, а перечень post-параметров, а внутри PARTNER json
>   массив параметров

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильным решением оказался следующий код

```
import json
import requests
data = {"PARTNER": str('{"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}')}
list_for_all = [] 
for n in range(5): 
    api_url = f"example.ru/api.php?action=getissues&page={n}"
    res1 = requests.post(api_url, data=data) 
    res = json.loads(res1.text) 
    res2 = res['RESULTS'] 
    list_for_all.append(res2) 
print(list_for_all)
```

на стороне сервера строка перерабатывается в json
Вряд ли кому то это поможет, на мой взгляд это специфичный случай

Answer (score 1):

А вы уверены, что данные правильно передаете?

В примере `php` вы передаете в `PARTNER` словарь:

```
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'PARTNER={"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}');
```

А в питоне `PARTNER` содержит список со словарем:

```
data = {"PARTNER": [{"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}]}
```

Попробуйте передать как в `php`:

```
data = {"PARTNER": {"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}}
```

---

**UPD.**

Раз нужно как `form` отправить, попробуйте так:

```
data = {"PARTNER": {"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}}

list_for_all = []
for n in range(5):
    api_url = f"https://example.ru/api.php?action=getissues&page={n}"
    res1 = requests.post(api_url, data=data)
...
```

Или так:

```
data = {"PARTNER": json.dumps({"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"})}
```

Указание параметра `data=` указывает в запросе `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, если же нужно поменять на `'application/json'`, то указывайте заголовок:

```
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}
...
    res1 = requests.post(api_url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

---

**PS.**

Советую, в случае вопросов передаваемых `requests` данных, [включать отладочное логирование](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3999156448673c2326957161b4ae214e1013b924/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10):

```
try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```

Comment: Не помогло. Результат тот же. Создатель API подсказывает, что PARTNER должен быть не ключом в json объекте, а параметром post запроса. Но как это сделать через модуль requests , если там в параметрах post запроса может быть только data и json я не понимаю.

Comment: Параметром post-запроса? В uri? типа ?PARTNER={"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}? Или отправить в запросе как form и внутри параметра PARTNER значением записать json? Обновил ответ

Comment: Цитата: Алексей
Не в uri, если в uri это будет get параметр, а нужен post

Comment: @RomanKV, в `post` тоже можно передавать в uri параметры, а не только в `get`, но это для общего развития, к текущему вопросу не имеет значения :)

Comment: правильным оказалось сделать вот так data = {"PARTNER": str('{"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}')}

Comment: @RomanKV, я этот вариант тоже писал: `data = {"PARTNER": json.dumps({"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"})}` :) `json.dumps(` вернет эту же строку и, кст, функцию строки можно не вызывать, т.к. у вас там и так строка, т.е. просто: `'{"0":"5401696","1":"5376079"}'`